# Binding event with parameters

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I am trying to call a function which accepts parameters with the `onFocus` event of an element. In addition, am trying to bind the `onFocus` event handler with all the elements of that form. Here is my code:

```
<!--HTML Code-->
<form name="form1" id="form1">
<input type="text" name="name"/>
<input type="text" name="age"/>
<input type="text" name="gender"/>
<textarea id="cmt" multiline="multiline"></textarea>
</form>
```

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
var f=document.getElementById("form1");
for(i=0;i<f.length-1;i++)
{
f.elements[i].onFocus=help(i);
}

function help(i)
{
Var help=new Array("Help for name","Help for age", "help for gender");
document.getElementById("cmt").value=help[i];
}
```

This code is not working. I have tried all variations of case sensitivity so don't answer if the answer is related to that. This code is not binding the event handler with the element and calling the function help for three times and the value of the textarea is being set as the final value of `i`.

Comment: were you perhaps looking for `f.children` ?

Comment: Yep, But I am looking for the form elements only. Labels and td tags in the form tag will also be called as its children but I want only input and textarea elements. The elements are accessible to extract attributes. The problem is with the event binding.

Answer (score 0):

There is some bugs in your code.

1. event handler name is "onfocus", not "onFocus".
2. you are calling help when when assigning it to "onfocus" event handler, instead of just passing name like "onfocus = help".
3. you can't pass arguments to help function with just assigning it to onfocus in this way. You have to use closure for such a purpose. But it will be more confusing and not proper solution of your requirement. So, instead of it you can check the target element using event object passed by browser in help function.

Here is link of jsfiddle. I hope that it will help you.
http://jsfiddle.net/parth1403/N9t5J/